# VC6 compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6, compiler-errors

there are some vs2005 c++ files in PJNSMTPCONNECTION Classes, but my application is in vc6,
now can any one tell whether CSTRINGA, CSTRINGW are available in vc6..
if not how overcome this problem

Comment: Any code snippet to illustrate?

Comment: Please try to describe your error properly. Relevant source code and the real compiler error messages helps a lot. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html for further tips that will help you ask questions the right way.

Comment: Ew VC6! (sorry had to say it).

Comment: Did you include head file for CString?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, CStringA and CStringW are in VC6.

Don't use VC6.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a direction to look: CStringA and CStringW are two specializations of CString, for ASCII (A) and wide-character (W) versions.

Comment: D:\src\SocMFC.h(74)  : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CString'
D:\src\SocMFC.h(76) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CString'

Answer (score 0):

Some basic tests in VC6 revealed that CStringW and CStringA are not recognized by the VC6 compiler.

However, the header file for CString (afx.h) specifies that it accepts both ANSI and Unicode inputs. Maybe you could just do

```
#define CStringA CString
#define CStringW CString
```